# Interpretation and truth table is enough to showing validity or a better way?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

I'm so glad that find this useful site. anyway, I ran into some challenging ways to find a formula is valid. Here is two example in my note that called valid. I ran into such a problem with making interpretation, anyone could help me what is the better way to showing these ones is valid !?1

(1) $ \exists y \forall x p(x,y) \to \forall x \exists y p(x,y) $

(2) $ \forall x \forall y p(x,y) \to \exists x \exists y p(x,y) $

Comment: Hi!  I'm glad you're excited to find this site.  You might like to rewrite your question though, to make it more precise.  Opinion-based questions are discouraged here.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 thanks so much. I means what is the formal way of showing these are valid !?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 from my notes.

Comment: I made a mistake in my earlier comment.  (2) is true, as long as we aren't dealing with the empty structure.  (1) is also true.  The way I'd show their validity is with a proof.  Do you know what these formulae mean?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 I need formal way.

Comment: Try reading the formulae out loud.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 I failed to do this, so I asked it here.

Comment: What did you fail to do?  More importantly, what have you succeeded in doing so far?  Questions asked on this site must show demonstrate effort on the part of the asker if they are to be answered.

Comment: It seems to me that we have find it already ... see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205681/validity-of-a-few-fol-formulas).

Comment: wow my example is mentioned in that link @MauroALLEGRANZA but why there is no answer?